# POST WITH TOKEN C #

Tags: c#, api, post, httprequest, token

I need to do this from C #, it's a post that works ok from the web, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I leave a picture of the F12 when I act on the web, I try to do the same in C # but I can't get it to work.

[image]

```cs
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var Token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
request.Headers.Add("accessToken", Token);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    var data = "lockId=xxxxx";
    streamWriter.Write(data);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `WebRequest`. Use `HttpClient`.

Comment: What part doesn't work?

Comment: From the web I do this function with a button and it returns this: {"data": {}, "errorCode": 0}

But when I try to do it from C # it returns an html code as if I would not have permission, to do the function, I am doing something wrong, the token is the one that gives permission to perform the action.